# Is it possilble to link .so file into .a file

Tags: gcc, hyperlink

Is it possilble to link .so file into .a file

A 3rd party only offer a so

Our .a lib depend on it.

And we don't want to give customer too much dependency

Comment: I don't think so since the address space inside the libs is supposed to be arranged differently. Maybe someone else has a more authoratative answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't convert a shared lib back to a static lib. There is information in the .o files that gets discarded when they are welded together into a .so file. If you really want static linking, you'll have to persuade the third party to also ship you an archive.